# "setup.py develop" installs git remote version instead of local version with live changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, setup.py

Normally when I develop a Python package for personal use, I use `python3 setup.py develop`, and then perform `pip3 install -e <path_to_package>` within another virtualenv, allowing me to hack around with both at the same time. When I do `gpip3 freeze` I see the path to the package on my local machine:

```
-e /Users/myName/Documents/testpackage
```

When I store that package on GitHub and clone it back onto a local machine, I expect to be able to use `setup.py develop` the same way and keep developing the package on my local machine, regardless of whether or when I push back to GitHub. However, when I do `gpip3 freeze`, I see:

```
-e git+git@github.com:github_username/repo_name@-----latest_commit's_sha_code-----#egg=repo_name&subdirectory=xx/xx/testpackage
```

I would like my system to keep track of the local version instead of git's remote.

Note: I know how to commit and push local changes to GitHub and install the egg in local environments. My goal is to quickly test ideas with a development version of the package without continuously integrating.

Note 2: The GitHub address given in `gpip3 freeze` fails when I try it in an environment (`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/myName/Documents/testenvironment/src/testpackage/setup.py'`)

But if I wanted pip3 to install the latest GitHub commit, I wouldn't be bothering with `setup.py develop` anyway.

Is there a way to signal to setup.py that I want it to ignore the remote in the cloned repo and pay attention only to the local path? Or is always referencing a remote when present the expected behavior of setup tools?

update : 
The wording of the output in `gpip3 freeze` after `python3 setup.py develop` when a remote isn't present (below) leads me to consider that tracking a remote whenever possible may be the intended behavior :

```
# Editable Git install with no remote (testpackage ==0.0.1)
-e /Users/myName/Documents/testpackage
```

I have been working around this by `git remote remove origin` when I want my local changes to be reflected in local environments without pushing a new commit, though unideal for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was rooted in a misunderstanding of how to implement `python3 setup.py develop`.

My original method was :

1) `python3 setup.py develop` from within the package directory itself, which would install/link the egg globally

2) `gpip3 freeze` to get (I thought) the link to the egg (seeing all the extra git remote info here was confusing to me)

3) `cd` to another virtual environment, `source bin/activate`, then call `pip3 install -e <link_copied_from_global_pip_freeze>`

In fact there is no need to call `python3 setup.py develop` from within the package under development, or to use `gpip3 freeze` to get the egg link.

I can go directly to the virtual env and activate it, then use `pip3 install -e <system_path_to_package_directory_containing_setup.py>`. This will create an egg link in the package directory if it doesn't already exist. Edits within the package are reflected in the virtual environment as expected, and I can use Git version control freely within the package according to my needs without interference.

I assume there may be times to call `python3 setup.py develop` directly (`setup.py develop --user` also exists) but by not doing so I happen to avoid littering my global environment with extra packages.

Related info from 2014 question in the Python [Disutils thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2014-April/024112.html) :

Questioner writes:

> For years, I've been recommending:
>
> $ python setup.py develop
>
> [...]
>
> Having said that, I also notice that:
>
> $ pip install -e .
>
> does the same thing.
>
> Should I be recommending one over the other?

Noah answers :

> You should recommend using pip for it, mostly because as you said that will work even with packages that don't use setuptools :-) It also is required when doing a develop install with extras, though that requires a slightly more verbose syntax due to a bug in pip.